# Outlook / hotmail free rules spam filter by keyword OR list

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, hotmail

I have a keylist of words I've put gathered from my spam email. I've created 4 rules that filter by subject,body,sender and KEYWORDs.

The filter doesnt work, I believe its because I have ALL of the words in each of the filters and its using AND logic instead oft OR. I've tried separating the words using a "," and "; with no luck.

The list is long and contains words I wouldnt post here.

Has anyone had success at this?

Adding each of these keywords as its own filter is possible but there are 50 or so, it would also make maintaining the list even more of a chore.

Comment: Are you using a Outlook desktop client? If so, you can set the rule "with specific words" in the subject. Then there is a list using "OR" logic.

Comment: Its the web interface that doesnt show that option. This site is not very friendly for uploading screen shots, I tried.